# Why is EhCacheProvider deprecated?

Tags: hibernate, caching, ehcache, terracotta

I am configuring my hibernate project to use a 2nd-level cache provider, so that I can take advantage of query caching.

I added a dependency to ehcache:

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

I think that the provider class I want to use is:

```
net.sf.ehcache.hibernateEhCacheProvider
```

When I look at the referenced libraries in eclipse, I see the `@Deprecated` annotation on `EhCacheProvider`, and also on `SingletonEhCacheProvider`. What gives? Is there an up-to-date replacement provider that I can use?

I am using hibernate version 3.4.0.GA, in case it matters.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> What gives? Is there an up-to-date replacement provider that I can use?

They have been deprecated in favor of the classes implementing the new Hibernate 3.3/3.5 SPI with its `CacheRegionFactory`. These implementations are respectively:

- `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory`
- `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`

Benefits of the new SPI include:

> - The SPI removed synchronization in the Hibernate cache plumbing. It is
>     left up to the caching implementation
>     on how to control concurrent access.
>     Ehcache, starting with 1.6, removed
>     syncrhonization in favour of a CAS
>     approach. The results, for heavy
>     workloads are impressive.
> - The new SPI provides finer grained control over cache region storage and
>     cache strategies. Ehcache 2.0 takes
>     advantage of this to reduce memory
>     use. It provides read only, nonstrict
>     read write and read write strategies,
>     all cluster safe.
> - Ehcache 2.0 is readily distributable with Terracotta Server Array. This
>     gives you cluster safe operation
>     (coherency), HA and scale beyond the
>     limits of an in-process cache, which
>     is how most Hibernate users use
>     Ehcache today. There is the existing
>     ehcache.jar and ehcache-terracotta.jar
>     which provides the client library. (...)

You are thus encouraged to use the new implementations. Configuration is done via the following property:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
    net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
```

That replaces the `hibernate.cache.provider_class` property.

#### References

- Hibernate Blog

  - [Ehcache 2.0 supports new Hibernate 3.3 caching provider](http://relation.to/Bloggers/Ehcache20SupportsNewHibernate33CachingProvider)
- EhCache documentation

  - [Upgrading From Ehcache versions prior to 2.0](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate-upgrade.html)
  - [Hibernate Second Level Cache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html)

Comment: Doesn't work here due to class : org.hibernate.cache.TimestampsRegion not being found. I have ehcache, jcache and hibernate 5 on the classpath ..

Answer (score 17):

if you wish to use **Hibernate 4.0.0.Final.** for the value of hibernate.cache.region.factory_class property use:

- `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` instead of `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` and
- `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory` instead of `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory`

Otherwise you will end up with some internal ClassNotFound exceptions

Comment: Very good point...here is the reason from a terracotta engineer : (http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/6674.page --> second post)

Answer (score 10):

EhCache 2 is now deprecated and discontinued. You should use EhCache 3 instead. In Hibernate versions after 5.3 it is recommended to use JSR-107 (JCache). In order to do that 2 dependencies are needed:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
     <version>your_hibernate_version</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The first one provides JSR-107 API compliant with Hibernate. The second one is actual cache implementation - EhCache 3.

Also new `RegionFactory` must be used:

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
```

Comment: JCache is ehcache ? I am confused. What is JCache. Why are EcacheREgionFactory classes still not deprecated. It is also not picking up the configuration file of EhCache.xml

Comment: @mmm Ehcache from version 3.0 is a JCache API implementation (also called JSR-107). Look at the Ehcache docs: https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/107.html

Comment: does that mean that I now have to annotate my entities? I did not have to do that before. My old configuration is not working now. I made a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484497/upgrading-to-hibernate-5-and-configuring-ehcache-not-working-jcache-now

Comment: In 2022, ehcache 3 and hibernate 5 in programatic approaches for legacy code (not using Cache annotations) is a hairball of dead links and confusion. JSR 107 seems only partly implemented.  I had to give up on ehcache 3 programatic configuration due to all the holes and class conflicts I was encountering.  Hibernate and ehcache teams have duplicate class entries in different package structures (e.g. EhCacheRegionFactory or when to use hibernate-ehcache).  Documentation and examples are sparse and inadequate.  I'm reading sources just to try and grok whats going on.

Comment: dead end. Failed to collect dependencies at org.ehcache:ehcache:jar:3.10.8 ->org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453 ->org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453 ->javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0-b161121.1438: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0-b161121.1438: Could not transfer artifact javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:pom:2.3.0-b161121.1438 from netbeans (http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Repository decommissioned. Please refer to https://netbeans.apache.org/about/oracle-transition.html

Answer (score 6):

The [EhCache docs](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html#Setting_Ehcache_as_the_Hibernate_Second_Level_Cache) say that from Hibernate 3.3 onward you should use:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
    net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
```

(or `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`)

Comment: FYI That EhCache doc link is dead.