# What are the implications of using SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory vs. EhCacheRegionFactory for Hibernate 2nd-level cache in a Web Application?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, ehcache

While integrating two subsystems, we were forced to use multiple **SessionFactory** instances, which lead to trouble when interacting with our Hibernate second-level cache (Terracotta EhCache). Specifically:

```
 for(CacheManager cm : CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS){
            LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG, "In cm " + cm.getName());
            for(String cn : cm.getCacheNames()){
                LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG, "I have a cache called " + cn);
                LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG, "it's status is " + ms.getCache(cn).getStatus());
            }
        }
  try{
     myCollection.size();
  }catch(IllegalStateException ise){
      LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ise);  //Triggered
  }
```

The debug print-out shows `STATUS_ALIVE` for cache "Foo" but the call to `size()` throws an **`IllegalStateException`**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Foo Cache is not alive.
```

Currently, both SessionFactories are configured to use **`SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`**. If I switch the SessionFactories to use **`EhCacheRegionFactory`** (non-singleton), what are the ramifications for cache behavior (specifically in a Web App context)?

Comment: You are using two session factories, but inside the same app? Are the factories similar, or are they configured separately?

Comment: Yes. We are migrating from an existing data model to a shiny new data model and we have to deal with both when integrating with legacy systems. So they're "similar" but not identical.

Comment: not sure if this helps: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3450

Comment: This link looks interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690212/507864

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EhCache will ensure that all instances of `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` use the same actual `CacheManager` internally, no matter how many instances of `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` you create, making it a crude version of the Singleton design pattern.

The plain `EhCacheRegionFactory`, on the other hand, will get a new `CacheManager` every time.

If you have two Hibernate session factories in Spring, each using their own instance of `SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory`, then they're actually going to end up sharing a lot of their cache state, which may account for your problem.

This isn't really a good match for Spring, where the singletons are supposed to be managed by the container. If you use `EhCacheRegionFactory`, then you'll likely get more predictable results. I suggest giving it a go and see how you get on.