# Hibernate error "net.sf.ehcache.CacheException"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate3.6.10 final version.I have build path and created classes and trying to run the application ,its shows error net.sf.ehcache.CacheException, so i have added the ecahe jar too.But even though it throwing the error. Please help me.

Jar screen shot.

[image]

Hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">******</property>
    <property name="connection.username">*****</property>
    <property name="connection.password">*****</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property> 
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.DAO.Part"/> 
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error Trace :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
        SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
        Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge]
        Dec 12, 2013 10:55:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ReleaseRegistrationAdminServlet threw exception
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.<init>(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:280)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
        at com.DAO.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:26)
        at com.DAO.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:18)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: @RC what version need to include for hibernate3.6.10 ?

Comment: I added hinerate ehcache-3.6.10.Fianl jar

Comment: Good, its working.Please post as answer, will accept it.

Comment: On a side note, it's a good idea to use `EHCacheRegionFactory` rather than the deprecated `EHCacheProvider` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689868/why-is-ehcacheprovider-deprecated#3690212)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add ehcache jar (from ehcache.org)

net.sf.ehcache / ehcache-core / 2.4.3 according to [mavenrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.6.10.Final)