# Upgrading to Hibernate 5 and configuring EhCache not working. JCache now?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, ehcache

I have these dependencies added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b11</version>
</dependency>
```

as well as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I used to also have

```
   properties.put ( Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.class.getName()  );
```

and
properties.put ( "net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "App/config/CacheConfig.xml" )

where `App/config/CacheConfig.xml` is:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="false">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000"
                  eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="300"
                  timeToLiveSeconds="600"
                  diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
                  diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="false">
    </defaultCache>

    <cache
            name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false">
    </cache>

    <cache
            name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="300">
    </cache>

    <!--
    If you are concerned about cpu utilisation and locking in the DiskStore, you can set the
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds to a high number - say 1 day. Or you can effectively turn it off by
    setting the diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds to a very large value
    -->
    <cache
            name="br.com.atlantico.toi.model.calc.Anomalia"
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="300"
            timeToLiveSeconds="600"/>
</ehcache>
```

**The problem** is that when I try to keep the SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory it fails with error:

```
  Unable to resolve name [net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]

  ... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
       ... org/hibernate/cache/TimestampsRegion
```

Ok, I looked online, and then it is suggested I use:

```
        properties.put(Environment.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, JCacheRegionFactory.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.javax.cache.provider", EhcacheCachingProvider.class.getName());
```

and

```
        properties.put("hibernate.javax.cache.uri", "App/config/CacheConfig.xml");
```

which works (but the old ehcache file does not work).

However, I believe that JCache use now, has to be used by annotating entities whereas before I just configured it in CacheConfig.xml (ehcache).

**Question 1.**

Is there a way to continue to use SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory with Hibernate 5, Ehcache 3?
If so how. It is not deprecated.

**Question 2.**

What is this new JCache, is it only method return caching? I am mostly interested in Second_level_cache and query cache.

**Question 3.**
How can I convert my old ehcache to the new one? I have not been able to find a sample ehcache file using the new version, because feeding the old will result in parsing errors basically.

```
      org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
          cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'.
```

Please fill in my lack of knowledge by educating me.

Comment: Did you fixed this? @mjs

Comment: Yes, I was, but I think I ended up dumping ehcache. I don't think it is needed. Just configure without.

Comment: Can u share your new configuration?